# What happens when returning on for-select loop with running goroutines

Tags: go

I'm trying to figure how can I shorten run times as much as possible when waiting for results on multiple goroutines. The idea is doing a for-select loop on retrieving messages from a channel (result channel) and breaking out of the loop when a result is false. Subsequently, potentially one or more goroutines are left running and I don't quite know what would happen in the background.

Consider this:

```
results := make(chan bool, int NumRequests)
go DoSomething(results) // DoSomething sends the result on results channel
go DoSomething(results) // DoSomething sends the result on results channel
go DoSomething(results) // DoSomething sends the result on results channel
for {
    select {
    case r := <- results:
        if !r {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

My question is - What would happen if I return while there are goroutines trying to sent their result to the channel? I've made a buffered results channel as seen above so the goroutines wouldn't deadlock while running. What would happen memory-wise when doing this? Will there be a goroutine leakage? What is the idiomatic way of doing something like this?

Comment: We can't say without knowing what `DoSomething` does. The goroutines need to return in order to release any memory they consume.

Comment: For the sake of it, lets just say it checks if a character is contained inside a string. If so, it returns `true` to the `results` channel, else it returns `false`. I would like to catch the first `false` and collapse the whole for-select statement.

Comment: There's still not enough info here to say with certainty. The goroutines need to return. That's all. If the channel capacity is enough to accept all results, and not block any goroutines, then you don't have a problem, and if some goroutines are blocked, then you do have a problem. You say the goroutine may be left running, but if you know that, then you know where it would be blocked and can fix it.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the whole pseudo code above is encapsulated in a function. When I return from a function as I did, will the results channel still be in memory and not raise a panic when goroutines try to send on it? The whole point is to buffer the channel in the length of my requests to `DoSomething` (in the case above, NumRequests will be 3), but I'm afraid some resources might leak when doing so.

Comment: If the `DoSomething` goroutines return, then there is no leak. The results channel will exist as long as something has a reference to it, it can't just disappear. If you want the goroutintes to be able to exit early, you need to provide another channel or context to notify them, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: That's exactly my question. By saying **as something has a reference to it**, do you mean that when I return from `if !r { return }` that the results channel deletes itself from memory?

Comment: Nothing "deletes itself from memory" (stack allocated variables kind of do, in a sense, but Go will heap allocate everything that requires it) Each goroutine has a reference to the channel that was passed in as a parameter, so the channel can't be collected until they have all returned. It comes back to my first statement -- the only thing you need to ensure is that the goroutines return.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the exact purpose behind cancellable contexts. Take a look at the example for [`context.WithCancel`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#WithCancel), it shows how to do exactly what you describe.

Comment: Neat. Tested it now and it works as expected. Thanks!